# Set screen sharing password via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, screensharing

I want to set the screen sharing password using apple script and check the option 'VNC viewers may control screen with password'.  I'm new at apple script, and what I have accomplished is only checking the 'Screen Sharing' option under the Sharing pane of System Preferences.

Here's what I have so far:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell checkbox 1 of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing" to if value is 0 then click
    end tell
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing"
        delay 1
        set value of text field 1 to "p"
    end tell
end tell
```

But the code above will prompt me an error:

```
Can’t get text field 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index
```

Comment: Please show us what you have so far and where you are stuck

Comment: Here's what I have so far @mcgrailm:

tell application "System Preferences"
 set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
 tell process "System Preferences"
  tell checkbox 1 of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing" to if value is 0 then click
 end tell
 
 tell process "System Preferences"
  click button 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing"
  delay 1
  set value of text field 1 to "p"
 end tell
end tell

But the code above will prompt me an error: Can’t get text field 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.

Comment: umm can you put that in your post please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell checkbox 1 of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing" to if value is 0 then click
    end tell
    tell process "System Preferences"
        delay 1
        click button 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing"
        tell sheet 1 of window "Sharing"
            tell checkbox "VNC viewers may control screen with password:" to if value is 0 then click
            delay 1
            set value of text field 1 to "p"
            click button "ok"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Specifically the text field (and "VNC viewers..." checkbox and "OK" button" are members of `tell sheet 1 of window "Sharing"`, so the `tell` needs to be adjusted appropriately.

In case you don't know them, a couple of tools which make this sort of thing easier:

1. The `Accessibility Inspector` is a little utility bundled in OSX (or perhaps its in xcode - not sure).  It gives a lot of information about whatever UI element in any window that your mouse is currently over.
2. `entire contents of` allows you to dump all UI elements in a given scope when using the Applescript Editor.  For example if I inserted `get entire contents of window "Sharing"` in the appropriate place in this script, it would list out all UI elements of the window "sharing" in the events panel of the Applescript editor.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.  But how would I automatically enter the password `coz the System Preferences is asking me the password for the logged in user of my mac?

Comment: @hnmpk - I'm not entirely sure.  Is this happening because the `System Preferences` dialog is locked with the "Click the lock to make changes"?  In my case, if this is locked, then the script fails altogether with `Can't get sheet 1 of window "sharing" ...`.  But I unlock it then run the script, it runs without issue.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it well.  Once the new VNC password is being set, it will prompt me with this `System Preferences want to make changes. Type your password to allow this.`  And I want it automated too.  Is this possible?